# Why does supplying an empty list to this Haskell function give compiler error?

Tags: haskell, recursion

This code is from the book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!":

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
maximum' [] = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximum' [x] = x  
maximum' (x:xs)   
    | x > maxTail = x  
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = maximum' xs
```

It works fine on non-empty lists, but supplying an empty list:

```
main = print $ maximum' []
```

gives this compiler error:

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘maximum'’
> prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.

Why is that? Shouldn't the code actually catch it when an empty list is supplied? I don't understand the error message.

Comment: It doesn't know the type of the element, you should specify this, for example with `maximum' ([] :: [Int])`

Comment: you don't have two signatures for the function, the signature in the comment is for the list.

Comment: If the function has an `Ord` constraint in its type, that means when you call it, the compiler needs to choose an `Ord` dictionary to pass; that is, the compiler needs to decide on a particular implementation of `(<)`, `compare`, etc. to give the function. This error happens when there is more than one possible choice and no way to decide at compile time.  A polymorphic type will not do, you have to decide on a specific concrete type, so that an `Ord` dictionary can be chosen.  (Even though it wouldn't be used in this case, it could be used by a function with the same type signature)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘maximum'’ prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.

This means that when you call `maximum' []`, the type of `[]` is not clear: it could be `[Int]` or `[()]` or something else.

In this particular case, the result happens to be the same for different types of the list. The compiler can't prove it here, and in general that's not the case. Consider this function:

```hs
readAndPrepend :: (Read a, Show a) => String -> [a] -> String
readAndPrepend s xs = show (read s : xs)
```

If you call `readAndPrepend "42" []`, it's ambiguous what the result should be:

```
ghci> readAndPrepend "42" ([] :: [Int])
"[42]"
ghci> readAndPrepend "42" ([] :: [Double])
"[42.0]"
ghci> readAndPrepend "42" ([] :: [()])
"[*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
ghci>
```

In other words, the `a` type variable is "unsolved", like a free `x` in a mathematical equation.

What you need to do is pick a type that you want the list to be and specify it explicitly:

```hs
main = print $ maximum' ([] :: [()])
```